# Exec command into a Pod using Kubernetes "client-go"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to exec a command into a pod, but I keep getting the error  `unable to upgrade connection: Forbidden`

I'm trying to test my code in development by doing `kubectl proxy` which works for all other operations such as creating a deployment or deleting it, however it's not working for executing a command, I read that I need `pods/exec` so I created a service account with such role like

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: dev-sa
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-view-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-exec-view-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["get","create"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods-svc-account
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dev-sa
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-view-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods-exec-svc-account
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dev-sa
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-exec-view-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

then I retrieve the bearer token for the service account and try to use it in my code

```
func getK8sConfig() *rest.Config {
    // creates the in-cluster config
    var config *rest.Config
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("DEVELOPMENT"))
    if os.Getenv("DEVELOPMENT") != "" {
        //when doing local development, mount k8s api via `kubectl proxy`
        fmt.Println("DEVELOPMENT")
        config = &rest.Config{
            Host:            "http://localhost:8001",
            TLSClientConfig: rest.TLSClientConfig{Insecure: true},
            APIPath:         "/",
            BearerToken:     "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InFETTJ6R21jMS1NRVpTOER0SnUwdVg1Q05XeDZLV2NKVTdMUnlsZWtUa28ifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZWZhdWx0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZWNyZXQubmFtZSI6ImRldi1zYS10b2tlbi14eGxuaiIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50Lm5hbWUiOiJkZXYtc2EiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC51aWQiOiJmZDVhMzRjNy0wZTkwLTQxNTctYmY0Zi02Yjg4MzIwYWIzMDgiLCJzdWIiOiJzeXN0ZW06c2VydmljZWFjY291bnQ6ZGVmYXVsdDpkZXYtc2EifQ.woZ6Bmkkw-BMV-_UX0Y-S_Lkb6H9zqKZX2aNhyy7valbYIZfIzrDqJYWV9q2SwCP20jBfdsDS40nDcMnHJPE5jZHkTajAV6eAnoq4EspRqORtLGFnVV-JR-okxtvhhQpsw5MdZacJk36ED6Hg8If5uTOF7VF5r70dP7WYBMFiZ3HSlJBnbu7QoTKFmbJ1MafsTQ2RBA37IJPkqi3OHvPadTux6UdMI8LlY7bLkZkaryYR36kwIzSqsYgsnefmm4eZkZzpCeyS9scm9lPjeyQTyCAhftlxfw8m_fsV0EDhmybZCjgJi4R49leJYkHdpnCSkubj87kJAbGMwvLhMhFFQ",
        }
    } else {
        var err error
        config, err = rest.InClusterConfig()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

    }

    return config
}
```

Then I try to run the [OpenShift example](http://people.redhat.com/jrivera/openshift-docs_preview/openshift-online/glusterfs-review/go_client/executing_remote_processes.html) to exec into a pod

```
    // Determine the Namespace referenced by the current context in the
    // kubeconfig file.
    namespace := "default"

    // Get a rest.Config from the kubeconfig file.  This will be passed into all
    // the client objects we create.
    restconfig := getK8sConfig()

    // Create a Kubernetes core/v1 client.
    coreclient, err := corev1client.NewForConfig(restconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create a busybox Pod.  By running `cat`, the Pod will sit and do nothing.
    var zero int64
    pod, err := coreclient.Pods(namespace).Create(&corev1.Pod{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: "busybox",
        },
        Spec: corev1.PodSpec{
            Containers: []corev1.Container{
                {
                    Name:    "busybox",
                    Image:   "busybox",
                    Command: []string{"cat"},
                    Stdin:   true,
                },
            },
            TerminationGracePeriodSeconds: &zero,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Delete the Pod before we exit.
    defer coreclient.Pods(namespace).Delete(pod.Name, &metav1.DeleteOptions{})

    // Wait for the Pod to indicate Ready == True.
    watcher, err := coreclient.Pods(namespace).Watch(
        metav1.SingleObject(pod.ObjectMeta),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for event := range watcher.ResultChan() {
        switch event.Type {
        case watch.Modified:
            pod = event.Object.(*corev1.Pod)

            // If the Pod contains a status condition Ready == True, stop
            // watching.
            for _, cond := range pod.Status.Conditions {
                if cond.Type == corev1.PodReady &&
                    cond.Status == corev1.ConditionTrue {
                    watcher.Stop()
                }
            }

        default:
            panic("unexpected event type " + event.Type)
        }
    }

    // Prepare the API URL used to execute another process within the Pod.  In
    // this case, we'll run a remote shell.
    req := coreclient.RESTClient().
        Post().
        Namespace(pod.Namespace).
        Resource("pods").
        Name(pod.Name).
        SubResource("exec").
        VersionedParams(&corev1.PodExecOptions{
            Container: pod.Spec.Containers[0].Name,
            Command:   []string{"date"},
            Stdin:     true,
            Stdout:    true,
            Stderr:    true,
            TTY:       true,
        }, scheme.ParameterCodec)

    exec, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(restconfig, "POST", req.URL())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Connect this process' std{in,out,err} to the remote shell process.
    err = exec.Stream(remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdin:  os.Stdin,
        Stdout: os.Stdout,
        Stderr: os.Stderr,
        Tty:    true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("done")
```

so it seems like the bearer token is getting ignored and isntead I'm getting the privileges of the kubectl admin.

How can I force the rest client to use the provided bearer token? 
Is this the right way to exec a command into a pod?

Comment: You should almost never script "exec"-type operations; change the code inside the container to do whatever work is necessary itself.  (Remember that the cluster can destroy and recreate pods on its own, especially if nodes fail and are removed from the cluster, and when a pod gets created anew your external "exec" process won't have run on it.)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the `privileges of the kubectl admin` because you are connecting
through `localhost` endpoint exposed by `kubeproxy`. This already authorizes you with 
your admin credentials.

I have replicated this and I have come up with this solution:

What you want to do is to connect directly to the API server. 
To retrieve API address use this command:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
```

Then replace that `localhost` address with the `APIserverIP` address

```
...
        config = &rest.Config{
            Host:            "<APIserverIP:port>",
            TLSClientConfig: rest.TLSClientConfig{Insecure: true},

...
```

Your code is creating a pod so you also need to add `create` and `delete` permissions 
to your `Service Account`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-view-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create", "delete", "get", "list", "watch"]
```

Let me know if that was helpful.